# Strip Tags and everything in between

Tags: php

How can i strip `<h1>including this content</h1>`

I know you can use strip tags to remove the tags, but i want everything in between gone as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you’re dealing with HTML, you should use an HTML parser to process it correctly. You can use PHP’s [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) and query the elements with [DOMXPath](http://php.net/domxpath), e.g.:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('//h1') as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: +1 Use a parser here. Do it right once, and won't have to revisit when you (or another dev, or a client using a WYSIYWG editor) invalidates the regex.

Comment: This look like a good solution however i only want to include the listing h1's not the actual page h1, if that makes sense. Ive noted this for other use though thank you.

Comment: @Andy just change the xPath selector to match only h1 inside a containing element.

Comment: +1 does the pretty well. However, can I add multiple tags search? Something like `$xpath->query('//h1//script//div')`?

Comment: Since nobody has replied to @asprin for 5.5 years, I guess I shall. To query multiple tags, just use the OR operator that you are familiar with. That means your code will look something like `$xpath->query('//h1|//script|//div')`

Comment: @JustCarty haha..5.5 years..omg..Thanks for responding...brings back old memories :)

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/<h1[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/h1[^>]*>/', '', '<h1>including this content</h1>');
```

**Example:**

```
echo preg_replace('/<h1[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/h1[^>]*>/', '', 'Hello<h1>including this content</h1> There !!');
```

**Output:**

```
Hello There
```

Comment: HTML allows plain `>` in attribute values.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to strip ALL tags and including content:

```
$yourString = 'Hello <div>Planet</div> Earth. This is some <span class="foo">sample</span> content!';
$regex = '/<[^>]*>[^<]*<[^>]*>/';
echo preg_replace($regex, '', $yourString);
#=> Hello  Earth. This is some  content!
```

HTML attributes can contain `<` or `>`. So, if your HTML gets too messy this method will not work and you'll need a DOM parser.

---

#### Regular Expression Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^>]*                    any character except: '>' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^<]*                    any character except: '<' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^>]*                    any character except: '>' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
```

Comment: HTML allows plain `>` in attribute values.

Comment: Gumbo, you beat me to this. I was just making an amendment :)

Comment: Wouldn't this leave you without any content at all, given that all HTML is inside the root node?

Comment: This works for me and I like the cleanliness of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an XSLT stylesheet and match all tags to themselves except for the h1 tag which would be matched to the empty string, and then apply it to your document. Might be a bit too heavy-weight for doing something as simple as this though.

Answer (score -3):

You also use strip_tags to remove the tags and also everything in between..

$html contain your html or php from where you want to remove the tags.

strip_tags($html,"");

Try this i think this will work for you.