# Strip tags in string PHP (also in source!)

Tags: c#, html

**I just deleted my question since I thought it was a duplicate of:
[Strip Tags and everything in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630159/strip-tags-and-everything-in-between)‌​
But: the options given there are only to 'hide' the tags. When checking the source code, the tags are all still there.**

When I look into the source of my code, my memo generates a whole new HTML page inside the .

```
<td>Memo:</td><td><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .cs95E872D0{text-align:left;text-indent:0pt;margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}
            .csEE99116A{color:#08343E;background-color:transparent;font-family:Arial; font-size:12pt; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span><p class="cs95E872D0"><span class="csEE99116A">dubbel test hoi</span></p></span></body>
</html>
</td>
```

Now, the only thing I want to see is `dubbel test hoi` in `<span><p class="cs95E872D0"><span class="csEE99116A">dubbel test hoi</span>` which I do see, but in the source it still looks shitty.

I tried all kind of function, most of them strip something but leave the CSS IDS, some just 'hide' it, so it's still available in the source code.

Any suggestions?

My input text is plaintext from a PHP form, then it goes into a DB and is sent to a C# application, which turns the text into RTF. In this page of my 'dashboard' I request the text, which is now in RTF, and transform the RTF to HTML text.

This is my code to transform the text into HTML text:

```
private string ConvertToHtml(string value)
        {
            if (RtfTags.IsRtfContent(value))
            {
                using (RichEditDocumentServer richServer = new RichEditDocumentServer())
                {
                    string htmlText = string.Empty;
                    richServer.RtfText = value;
                    CharacterProperties cp = richServer.Document.BeginUpdateCharacters(richServer.Document.Range);
                    cp.FontName = "Arial";
                    cp.FontSize = 12;
                    cp.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#08343e");
                    richServer.Document.EndUpdateCharacters(cp);
                    htmlText = richServer.HtmlText;
                    return htmlText;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is your input document? Can you show your code?

Comment: You could try a regular expression match or a html dom parser. But any given suggestion depends on how your source is formatted, therefor I support @hek2mgl's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#17656  a solution for this.
Just replace the style code then use strip_tags:

```
$htmlstring = preg_replace("'<style[^>]*>.*</style>'siU",'',$htmlstring);
echo strip_tags($htmlstring);
```

Comment: Don't understand how I could've missed this one. Thanks, seems like this works!