# PHP-How to remove element by tag name and its content

Tags: php, dom

I have a string and I want to delete `<style>` from it.
I am trying the following

```
$description    =   $product_info['description'];
$doc =   new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($description);
$list    =   $doc->getElementsByTagName('style');
while($list->length >0) {
   $p   =   $list->item(0);
   $p->parentNode->removeChild($p);
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

but it is not removing `<style>` from the output.

```
<style>.textleft{ margin-bottom:10px; float:left; display: inline-block; width:56%; text-align:left; padding-right:20px; padding-left:20px; } .textleft > p { display: table-cell; height: 150px; vertical-align: middle; } .imageblock{ display:inline-block; margin-bottom:10px; width: 44%; } .textright{ margin-bottom:10px; float:right; display: inline-block; width:56%; text-align:left; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; } .containerz{ display:block; } .featimage{ vertical-align:middle; display:inline-block; width:53%; max-height:245px; } .features{ vertical-align:middle; display:inline-block; width:46%; padding-left:30px; } .textright > p { display: table-cell; height: 150px; vertical-align: middle; } @media screen and (max-width: 991px) { .textleft, .textright, .imageblock{ width:100%; float:none; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; } /*.imageblock > img { width:100%;}*/ .containerz {text-align:center;} .textright > p, .textleft > p { height: 100%; } .textright, .textleft { margin-bottom: 0px; } .features, .featimage { padding-left: 0px; width:100%; float:none;} .features { padding-top: 10px;} .imageblock {margin-bottom: 25px;} } </style> <h1><strong>WhiteCoat Clipboard<sup>&reg;</sup> - TEAL&nbsp;- Vertical Metric Medical Edition</strong></h1>
```

Or if there is any other way to remove `<style>` and its contents?

Comment: Would [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags) work for you situation?

Comment: I have tried `strip_tags` it only strips `<style>` not its contents

Comment: Then I think you will need to first add it to the dom, and then remove it.  Otherwise, you're just dealing with a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272726/how-to-delete-element-with-domdocument

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630159/strip-tags-and-everything-in-between

Comment: tried that but issue is still same, I am seeing `style` tag in output