# How to skip div class from td tag while scraping web table in php?

Tags: php, web-scraping, html-table, file-get-contents

i am trying to scrape this table using php file_get_contents it has some even odd rows in the table, i want to skip all the div class ="showsmall" from td tag because its appending the table data of some column.. i have provided codes below, any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance..

**table**

```
<table class="table table-striped runtable">
 <thead class="ampstart-caption">
  <tr>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>col2</th>
    <th>col3</th>
    <th>
      "Actual col4"
      <div class="showsmall"> Actual col5</div>
    </th>
    <th>Actual col5</th>
    <th>col6</th>
  </tr>
 </thead> 

  <tbody class="ampstart-caption">
<tr class>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>20</td>
  <td>
     "Add"
    <div class="showsmall">
      "10 S dir"
      <span class="grn">(+100)</span>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
      "10 S dir"
      <span class="grn">(+100)</span>
  </td>
  <td>30</td>
</tr>

<tr class="even">
  <td>2</td>
  <td>30</td>
  <td>40</td>
     "Add"
    <div class="showsmall">
      "20 S dir"
      <span class="red">(-100)</span>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      "20 S dir"
      <span class="red">(-100)</span>
    </td>
  <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**php code**

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//table')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $rows) {
    $cells = $rows->getElementsByTagName('td');        
    if( $cells->length > 1 ){
        //$cells2 = $rows->getElementsByTagName('th');
        //echo '<pre>';

    echo "<tr>";
        //Get scrapped columns
        echo "<td>" . $nos[] = $cells->item(0)->textContent . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $col2[] = $cells->item(1)->textContent . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $col3[] = $cells->item(2)->textContent . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $col4[] = $cells->item(3)->textContent . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $col5[] = $cells->item(4)->textContent . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $col6[] = $cells->item(5)->textContent . "</td>";
```

**actual result**

```
i am getting output like 

no  col2  col3  Actual col4         Actual col5     col6

1   10    20    Add10 s dir(+100)   10 s dir(+100)  30   
2   30    40    Add20 s dir(-100)   20 s dir(-100)  50
```

**Expected result**

```
i want output like this 

no  col2  col3  Actual col4         Actual col5     col6

1   10    20    Add                 10 s dir(+100)  30   
2   30    40    Add                 20 s dir(-100)  50
```

Comment: Mabye somethink like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630159/strip-tags-and-everything-in-between

Comment: @MilanMajer hi..tried above question but its removing alternate rows..can you please add some php code using above reference..