# why does the_excerpt() add <p> tags to table data when i do not allow table tags in the excerpt?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress theme. I am trying not to allow any data from tables to show in the automatic post excerpt on the homepage of my blog. I am however allowing `<p>` tags. The data in the table in the post page does not have `<p>` tags but are instead in `<td>` tags. When I view the excerpt it produces all of the table data under one big `<p>` tag which is visible. How can I prevent this from happening?

If i put in a manual excerpt it overides what would be automatically shown so i have no problems with that method. But it feels like a workaround whereas i would like to fix the actual problem.

On a side note, if I allow table tags and all of its children in the excerpt it completely breaks the lower half of my webpage which uses CSS Grid, putting the sidebar, which is in the 3rd column of the grid, inside of it, meaning there is now a total of only 2 columns. Its very strange.

So i am mainly seeking to display no table data in the excerpt, but would be interested to know if anyone has any ideas about the second problem, although not necessary.

If i need to produce the code as an example let me know which code as i feel i would need to produce a lot of it and the fact it would only work in wordpress means it won't work here.

EDIT: Adding code:

PHP function
    //allow html in excerpts

```
function new_wp_trim_excerpt($text) {
    $raw_excerpt = $text;
    if ( '' == $text ) {
      $text = get_the_content('');

      $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );

      $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
      $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);

      $text = strip_tags($text, '<blockquote><q><cite><td><a><p><br><ol><ul> 
      <li>');
      $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);

      $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
      $words = preg_split('/[\n|\r|\t|\s]/', $text, $excerpt_length + 1, 
       PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
    if ( count($words) > $excerpt_length ) {
        array_pop($words);
        $text = implode(' ', $words);
        $text = $text . $excerpt_more;
    } else {
        $text = implode(' ', $words);
    }
}
return apply_filters('new_wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);

}
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'new_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

PHP calling the excerpt:

```
<div class="latest-news">
            <h1>Latest News</h1>
        </div>

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
?>

                <div class="home-posts-content">
                   <?php the_title('<h2 class="loop-headers"><a href="' . 
get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">', '</a></h2>'); ?>
                   <div class="loop-post-meta">
                        <p><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
                        <p>Posted by <?php the_author(); ?></p>
                    </div>
                   <div class="post-content">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="<?php 
 the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div><!--end .post-content-->
               </div><!--end .home-post-content-->
            <?php 

            endwhile; 

            else :

                _e( 'There are currently no posts available.', 'textdomain' 
);

            endif;


            ?>
        <div class="loop-pagination">
            <div class="prev">
                <?php previous_posts_link() ?>
            </div>
            <div class="next">
                <?php next_posts_link(); ?>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div><!--end .post-container-->
```

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing some of your code.  How do you "not allow data from tables"?  Also, it'd be nice to see sample "input" (eg, the post content), how you call the_excerpt, and the sample output (the HTML that is rendered).  Show the code, don't worry about the fact it "won't run here" - we deal with lots of questions where the code isn't runnable directly in SO.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. By "not allow data from tables" I suppose I should have explained further. I have a function that makes it so that I can allow certain tags such as <p>, <li>, <ul> and others in the excerpt but have not added table tags to it, so I suppose it's really just Wordpress that isn't allowing the table tags automatically. I have added the function to my original post as well as the html and php that I use to call the_excerpt(). You can also view the in-progress website at http://staging.irish-go.org/. The issue is with the first post 'Sample Table'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `echo get_the_excerpt()` instead of `the_excerpt()`. The second method adds p tags around your content, according to the documentation: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/#more-information

> Displays the excerpt of the current post after applying several
>   filters to it including auto-p formatting which turns double
>   line-breaks into HTML paragraphs.

Comment: Ok, I have done that. it has removed the <p> tags but the content is still showing. Now in the console it just shows up as tagless text. You can view the post I'm talking about as the first 'Latest News' post at this page: http://staging.irish-go.org/

Comment: For that, have a look at how to allow html tags in your excerpts. Here's a thread: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt

Comment: If you look at my EDIT in my original post you can see that I am allowing certain tags similar to as is described in the link you mentioned. Also if you look at the next post on my webpage 'Ninja Table Post', that post contains only a table via a plugin and it is not displaying anything in the excerpt. That is how I want the non-plugin tables to act.

Comment: I just noticed that your original answer does in fact answer the title of this post, but I suppose it wasn't the ultimate aim of my question. I'm looking to remove all content in the excerpt that comes from a table. Should I change the post title?

Comment: Ah I see, yeah the title is a bit misleading. I think your issue might be related to strip_tags, note that it does not remove the inner html for the tags it's stripping. So in your case, it removes the <table> tags, but leaves the inner html behind. If you want to remove the content too, you need to do some structure manipulation. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630159/strip-tags-and-everything-in-between

Comment: Ok. This looks a bit above my level of PHP understanding. Will need to dig around to understand it more. Thanks.